# Nextjs 13, deployed app not showing "/" default route (404 error)

Tags: routes, next.js, deployment, server, build

I have the problem that I deployed my app on a Linux server, unfortunately it does not recognize the default page (Home) because it is in the app folder as page.tsx. How do I get it out that the default page can also be read as a route "/"?

It's shwing me 404 Page not found error, all other routes working as expected.

There are no problems locally on my computer.

Can someone help me there?

Thanks